# something automatically multiply my values per 1000 in plots

Tags: python-3.x, plot, qt-designer, pyqtgraph

I have a GUI where I plot concentrations against position. At some points (it seems to be when my datapoints are below 0.1) the plotted values are multiplied by 1000 and ‘m’ is added to the unit (I suppose for ‘milli’, except my values are already in mmol, leading to an hugly ‘mmmol’). Like in the following figure with the following datapoints:

```
   0    0.01251502
  0.25  0.01188927
  0.75  0.01032489
  1.25  0.01063777
  1.75  0.00938626
  2.5  0.00782189
  3.5  0.00594463
  5    0.00344163
  7   0.0015643
  9   0.00093863
  12  0.0
```

Do you know how to disable this normalization ?
[image]
Unfortunately, I do not reproduce the problem with a basic plot, so I do not know where this weird normalization occurs (I use python 3.5 with pyqtgraph and a GUI built with QT designer) and did not write a clean code to show. My first hope was this is an obvious problem (like an obvious option) that you could identify without the code.

Comment: Could you please post the code for the basic plot & the QT designer plot?

Comment: @WoodyDev: text updated to explain I don't have a code convenient for bebugging. I will see that in forthcoming days if required

Comment: At the very least, please provide the line(s) associated with the pyqtgraph.plot function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of [`pyqtgraph.PlotItem.setLabel()`](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/plotitem.html#pyqtgraph.PlotItem.setLabel). If you do not want it to do this, include the units as part of the string `text` instead of using the `units` keyword in `setLabel`.

Comment: Pyqtgraph documentation isn't as easy to understand as stack exchange. :)